# find the max count of transactions in a time-bin for a grouped datetime column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My question is relevant to my previous question but it is different. So, a new post is created.

I would like to get max count in a 10-minutes bin for a datetime column in pandas dataframe.

my table:

```
 id1       date_time               adress       a_size         
 reom      2005-8-20 22:51:10      75157.5413   ceifwekd         
 reom      2005-8-20 22:55:25      3571.37946   ceifwekd         
 reom      2005-8-20 11:21:01      3571.37946   tnohcve          
 reom      2005-8-20 11:22:09      97439.219    tnohcve          
 reom      2005-8-20 11:25:09      97439.219    efgrcaw          
 penr      2005-8-20 17:07:16     97439.219    ceifwekd          
 penr      2005-8-20 19:10:37      7391.6258    ceifwekd         
 ....
```

i need:

```
 id1       date_time               adress       a_size         max_transaction
 reom      2005-8-20 22:51:10      75157.5413   ceifwekd         2
 reom      2005-8-20 22:55:25      3571.37946   ceifwekd         2
 reom      2005-8-20 11:21:01      3571.37946   tnohcve          3 
 reom      2005-8-20 11:22:09      97439.219    tnohcve          3
 reom      2005-8-20 11:25:09      97439.219    efgrcaw          3
 penr      2005-8-20 17:07:16     97439.219    ceifwekd          1
 penr      2005-8-20 19:10:37      7391.6258    ceifwekd         1
```

the max_transaction is the max count of transactions in the bins of 10-minutes.

e.g,

```
reom      2005-8-20 11:21:01      3571.37946   tnohcve          3 
reom      2005-8-20 11:22:09      97439.219    tnohcve          3
reom      2005-8-20 11:25:09      97439.219    efgrcaw          3
```

here, "reom" has 3 transactions from 11:21:01 - 11:25:09, which is in a 10-minutes bin.

My code:

```
 df['num_per_10_min'] = df.groupby(['id1',df['date_time'].dt.floor('10Min')])['date_time'].agg('count')
```

does not work.

```
  TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `transform` and `np.size`:

```
 df['num_per_10_min'] = (df.groupby(['id1',df['date_time'].dt.floor('10Min')])
                          .date_time.transform(np.size))
```